# Problem in printing the files which are different in 2 folders

Tags: python, comparison

```py
import os

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    # Function to compare files
    pass

def compare_folders(folder1, folder2):
    differences_found = False
    
    # Compare files in folder1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
        for file in files:
            file1 = os.path.join(root, file)
            file2 = os.path.join(root.replace(folder1, folder2, 1), file)
            if not os.path.exists(file2):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {folder1} but not in {folder2}")
                differences_found = True
            elif os.path.isfile(file2):
                # If the file exists in both folders, compare them
                compare_files(file1, file2)
    
    # Compare files in folder2
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder2):
        for file in files:
            file1 = os.path.join(root.replace(folder2, folder1, 1), file)
            file2 = os.path.join(root, file)
            if not os.path.exists(file1):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {folder2} but not in {folder1}")
                differences_found = True

    if not differences_found:
        print("No differences found between the files in the two folders.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder1 = input("Enter path to the first folder: ")
    folder2 = input("Enter path to the second folder: ")
    
    compare_folders(folder1, folder2)
```

I am trying to compare the files in both folders and print out the contents which are different from each other. As  well the file name which are different in both folders

Comment: What is your exact question?  You may want to [edit] your post for more clarity.

Comment: Hi. I am trying to compare the files in 2 folders. But my script is not printing all the files which are different. For example I have 8 files. 6 are same in both folders. I have 2 files in folder 1 and another 2 in folder1 but instead pf showing me all the files which are different it's showing 1 file name for each folder which are different. It's not reading the other files which have different name @ – 
PM 77-1

Comment: As I suggested, [edit] your question and include your problem description there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

1. `compare_files` is not currently doing any comparison. It should compare the two input files first for size and only then check whether the contents are the same. It should return True or False according to whether the files compare equal and that return value should be used to set `differences_found`.
2. If you find a difference between two files or if the file exists in one directory but not the other, the message you produce does not display the full paths to the files; you are only outputting the root folder names.
3. You have:

```py
def compare_folders(folder1, folder2):
    differences_found = False
    
    # Compare files in folder1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
        for file in files:
            file1 = os.path.join(root, file)
            file2 = os.path.join(root.replace(folder1, folder2, 1), file)
            if not os.path.exists(file2):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {folder1} but not in {folder2}")
                differences_found = True
            elif os.path.isfile(file2):
                # If the file exists in both folders, compare them
                compare_files(file1, file2)
...
```

I believe this should be:

```py
def compare_folders(folder1, folder2):
    differences_found = False

    # Compare files in folder1
    for root1, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
        for file in files:
            file1 = os.path.join(root1, file)
            root2 = root1.replace(folder1, folder2, 1)
            file2 = os.path.join(root2, file)
            if not os.path.isfile(file2):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {root1} but not in {root2}")
                differences_found = True
            else:
                # If the file exists in both folders, compare them
                if not compare_files(file1, file2):
                    print(f"Files {file} differ in {root1} and {root2}")
                    differences_found = True
...
```

This not only prints out the full paths to the files starting from the initial folders but also corrects a small bug: What if we have file folder1/a/b/test but folder2/a/b/test exists but it is a directory instead of a file. Your current would not show that file test exists in one directory but not the other and will not have set the `differences_found` flag.

I have provided an implementation of `compare_files` in the complete code below:

```py
import os
import mmap

def compare_files(file1: str, file2: str) -> bool:
    """Function to compare files."""

    with open(file1, 'rb') as f1, open(file2, 'rb') as f2:
        size1 = f1.seek(0, 2)
        size2 = f2.seek(0, 2)
        if size1 != size2:
            return False
        if size1 == 0:
            return True

        with mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm1, \
        mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mm2:
            return mm1[0:] == mm2[0:]

def compare_folders(folder1: str, folder2: str) -> None:
    differences_found = False

    # Compare files in folder1
    for root1, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
        for file in files:
            file1 = os.path.join(root1, file)
            root2 = root1.replace(folder1, folder2, 1)
            file2 = os.path.join(root2, file)
            if not os.path.isfile(file2):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {root1} but not in {root2}")
                differences_found = True
            else:
                # If the file exists in both folders, compare them
                if not compare_files(file1, file2):
                    print(f"Files {file} differ in {root1} and {root2}")
                    differences_found = True

    # Compare files in folder2
    for root2, dirs, files in os.walk(folder2):
        for file in files:
            root1 = root2.replace(folder2, folder1, 1)
            file1 = os.path.join(root1, file)
            file2 = os.path.join(root2, file)
            if not os.path.isfile(file1):
                print(f"File {file} exists in {root2} but not in {root1}")
                differences_found = True

    if not differences_found:
        print("No differences found between the files in the two folders.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder1 = input("Enter path to the first folder: ")
    folder2 = input("Enter path to the second folder: ")

    compare_folders(folder1, folder2)
```

**The above code works for me, so if you are still having difficulties, you need to explicitly show minimal directory structures that are not producing the results you expect along with what your expected result is and what you actually display.**

Comment: Thank you! But that's still not showing up all the files that I added in folder1 and folder2. for example folder 1 has test.txt and test1.txt and folder 2 has test3.txt. But the output printed as test.txt is in folder1 but not in floder2. It didnt talk about other files.

Comment: I want the script to loop through both folder 1 and folder 2. Print any differences like any addtional files which are not present in other directory. Also if the same name files in 2 directories if they have differences then print the content which are different

Comment: You said **for example folder 1 has test.txt and test1.txt and folder 2 has test3.txt. But the output printed as test.txt is in folder1 but not in floder2.** That's exactly correct: test.txt is *not* in folder2, which only has test3.txt according to what you just wrote. Are you saying it should have also indicated test1.txt was missing from folder2 but did not?

Comment: It's working fine. It can print the files which are not present in other directory or folder. Also, it print out the files names which has different content with same file name in other folder. Now, I am trying to print out the contents  which are different in both folder. Any tips for this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by “print out the contents”? Do you mean a line-by-line difference report?

Comment: Hi @Booboo yes I want the script to read line by line and give the output which were added in folder 2 files which are also present in folder1 but the contents are different. I want it to print only the difference, not the entire thing.

Comment: This is now a new requirement. Linux has a `diff` utility that will perform a line-by-line comparison. On other platforms you can download public-domain versions of `diff`. Then you need to invoke the utility specifying the paths to the files to be compared. For this look at `subprocess.Popen`. Then if you have difficulties in getting it to work, post a new question with your attempt (you can post a comment here with a link to the new question and I will try to look at it). For now, if I have solved your initial issue consider *accepting* my answer.

Comment: yes you solved my initial question. Thanks

Comment: Don’t thank me. Instead accept  the answer. Look at the link that I posted in my previous comment.